# WordPress thumbnail as a link

Tags: wordpress

here is a code I came up with to display 5 latest news with thumbs

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
echo '
<li><a>' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li>
';
if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
        echo '
<li>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'mini70') . '</li>
';

    }
}
?>
```

The problem is I'd like to display the thums as a link also but whatever I tried did not work
any help appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the link for the featured image:

```
<?php
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
    echo $thumb_url[0];
?>
```

Add the above to your code in the place you want to show the thumbnail.
Sourced from [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-get-the-post-thumbnail-url-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

many thanks to your reply, I still learning and every little helps
but it's not what I really wanted. Probably I should explain better in the first place? because I wanted to link the image to the same post
I managed to do it using

```
   <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';       
if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'mini70').'</a> </li> ';

}
}
?>
```

Looks to be no brainer, but I still struggled :)